# Валидация input FALSE or TRUE

Tags: javascript, jquery

### Как переменной `bool` вернуть ложь или истину, если `input` заполнен по шаблону `pattern="..."`?

```
 var bool = $('input:valid'); // я делал так, думал будеть false or true, а в итоге вернуло весь обьект, аха.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужен метод [checkValidity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/checkValidity):

```js
 input.onchange = () => console.log(input.checkValidity())
```

```html
<input id='input' pattern="\d{2,}" />
```